# not highlighting when click the button on left-edge of the screen, but fire event

Tags: ios

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 400, 200)];
    [btn setTitle:@"123" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitle:@"234" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(test11) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}

- (void)test11 {
    NSLog(@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
}
```

When I click the button on the screen-left, `test11` is working but not highLighting. When I click the button in another area, `test11` is working and highLighting. Different devices and iOS versions are behaving differently:

- iPhone 6s plus: not highlighting with iOS 9.2.2 and 9.3.2
- iphone 7: not highlighting
- iphone 6 plus: highlight with iOS 10.1
- All simulators are highLighting

Comment: Try to add more title/color for UIControlStateSelected. I'm not sure. Pls just try

Comment: Just I make a test, it doesn't matter,are you have other code

Comment: different iphone effect is not the same.6splus not high  with system 9,2,2 and 9.3.2. iphone 7 is not highlight. but in iphone 6plus is highlight with system 10.1;

Comment: Fix code formatting, and clarity

Comment: Thanks To George Green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the issue is that when you tap the left most side of the button, it is not showing the touch highlight?

This is because the touch handling on the button is conflicting with the screen edge gesture recogniser and so does not transition to recognised state until the tap is complete.

If you think about it:

1. User touches finger down, it could be a tap or a screen edge pan.
2. User holds finger down (here you want the touch highlight), still unsure if touch is a tap or a pan (user could still pan sideways)
3. User releases finger, the system now knows that the touch was a tap so can fire the event for it. 3.

Checkout what other recognisers are active in your hierarchy, if you have a UINavigationController it has a left screen edge recogniser by default for the back gesture. This is often the culprit for this issue. You can disable this recogniser if you want, or implement it's delegate to make it play ball with your buttons.

Comment: if i close 3D-touch of the system,the result is highLighting;but in xcode, what i do can work hightLighting